# C++ For loop is only processing final entry of a vector list

Tags: c++, file, vector

Within my main program I have a function that looks something like the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < partsVector.size(); i++) {

if(newChar == "A") {

 cout << newChar <<  endl;
} else {
  cout << "Character not found";
}

}
```

The program runs in reference to this text file, which itself has been stored in a vector(hence partsVector)(PS ive only added partCode to the list as i stopped and had issus)

```
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
```

In reference to this snippet(I will be including the full program), the issue is when it runs it returns "No character exists" returns when newChar is A, which as seen in the text file, there is an example where A exists. I can print the vector list through an enhanced for loop and it returns as expected. 
Im wondering whats wrong with my loop in which it goes through the vector list and stops at the last entry, and only uses that in test the condition?

FULL CODE

Main

```
include "driver.h"
#include "implementation.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

readFile();
writeFile();
robotComplexity();


getch();
return 0;

}
```

Implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//declaration of parts variables
char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;

std::vector<string> partsVector;
std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

std::string newChar;
std::stringstream convertChar;

void readFile() 
{

   std::string line;

while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    line.pop_back();//removing '.' at end of line
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);

    convertChar << partCode;
    convertChar >> newChar;

    // then read each element by delimiter
    int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {//spilt into different records
      switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count

      case 0:
        newChar = token; //convert partCode from a char to a string 
        break;
      case 1:
        partName = token;
        break;
      case 2: newChar2 = token;
        break;
      case 3: minimum = stoi(token);
        break;
        case 4: complexity = stoi(token);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      counter++;//increasing counter
    }
partsVector.push_back(newChar);
   } 

double robotComplexity() { 

double complexity = 10;

for(int i = 0; i < partsVector.size(); i++) {

if(newChar == "A") {
 cout << newChar <<  endl;
} else {
  cout << "Character not found";
}

} 
   if(complexity > 100) {
      complexity = 100;
   }

cout << "\nThe Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
return complexity;
} 

}
```

The main function of the code i am having issues with is too loop through the vector list until it finds an instance of partCode, converted to a string and now called newChar, which is equal to A. As of now the program loops through till the end(IE when it is equal to "E") and stops there and only uses that for the comparison.
Thankyou for any help

Comment: So I'm a little confused, your test `if(newChar == "A")` tests a global variable, it doesn't test anything in the `partsVector`. All your loop does it repeat the same test five times (because `partsVector` contains five items). I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to achieve. You are a little confused by all these global variables. If you are writing a function that is searching for an item in a list **then pass the item to search as a parameter to the function and preferably the list to be searched as well**. Coding is so much easier without global variables.

Comment: @john If newChar is set to E then it returns a character E. Global variables has nothing to do with the code not working how i intend it to, though i do understand. I even asked a friend and he told me all the code works accept that its only taking in the last stored value of the vector into the array. If you're confused on what i want please read the last paragraph, I make it clear.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, nothing you are saying about the code matches up the code you have posted. If you want to write a loop that looks for something in a vector, then your loop **must test the vector**, your loop does nothing like this. Sorry I can't help I'm just confused.

Comment: I think that you want to write a loop something like this `for(int i = 0; i < partsVector.size(); i++) { if (newChar == partsVector[i]) ...` You see how that code actually tests `partsVector`? But I could easily be completely wrong.

Comment: Through my own manipulation I was able to do it!, Thankyou

Comment: @john would you be able to help with converting an int to a string by any chance?

Comment: It's easy, in the `<string>` header is a function called `std::to_string` which converts any numeric type to a `std::string` see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string